# Android: Running app using USB Debugging

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get a map app on to my phone. I know you can do this by USB debugging. But ever since I set up the map in the app, it keeps running in the Google API AVD rather than going on the phone.

Then, if I change the AVD to 2.1/2.2 it comes up with error in the maps sections because the maps libraries aren't there.

How can I get this solved and get my app onto the phone? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, go to Run > Debug Configurations then select your project name under "Android Application" on the left. Then go to the Targets tab and switch from automatic to manual. This way it will ask you whether you want to use the device or emulator each time you run the app.